# glPushMatrix() / glPopMatrix() doesn't work

Tags: opengl, matrix, transformation

I am new to opengl.In my code,I have used glPushMatrix() / glPopMatrix() and draw my picture after use **glPushMatrix() / glPopMatrix()**.But it doesn't work,in other words,the variable nScale doesn't changed by my mouse controll.

Comment: BTW: You shouldn't use the fixed function matrix stack at all. It's deprecated and using it together with shaders is a bit arcane.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply your transformations **before** issuing the draw calls that you want the transformations applied to. Your posted code has this sequence:

```
glPushMatrix();
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
...
glEnd();
glScalef(nScale, nScale, 1.0f);
glPopMatrix();
```

Since the `glScalef()` comes after the draw calls, it will not influence them. The `glPopMatrix()` call will then undo the transformation specified by the `glScalef()` call. Since there are no draw calls between `glScalef()` and `glPopMatrix()`, the `glScalef()` call has no effect.

If you want to apply the scale factor to your rendered quads, you need to move the `glScalef()` call before the draw calls:

```
glPushMatrix();
glScalef(nScale, nScale, 1.0f);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
...
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```